# How to sync image folder along with data to remote server

Tags: php, linux

I am syncing the data from local system to remote server through `PHP`, data syncing correctly to remote server, but I have some folder(folder contains images) too sync along with data, how to sync folder from local system to `REMOTE SERVER` with `PHP`,
I am trying with

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('http://www.***.com:/tmp', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', '');
ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/upload', 'www.***.com:/tmp', 0777);
```

but its not working...

anyone can help?

Comment: I think there are some nice tools for this. Have you tried to google it?

Comment: now is it clear what i want to do?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if this edit is sufficient to reopen your question. I think you'll need to pinpoint the issue more. Maybe you can ask a new question about how to copy a file to another server with PHP.